# What is different between post_navigation() and get_the_post_navigation();?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

What is difference between these WordPress functions, and how to implement it?

```
the_post_navigation(); get_the_post_navigation();
the_archive_title(); get_the_archive_title();
the_post_pagination(); get_the_post_navigation();
the_archive_description(); get_the_archive_description();
```

I already googled for this, but I'm still not getting it right.

Comment: Basic difference between is that the_post_navigation() is parent function of get_the_post_navigation(). means the_post_navigation() includes and echo function named get_the_post_navigation(). You can see in the core file of wordpress https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2343

Answer (score 0):

All the functions that starts with `get_` are only **returning** the "result" of the function : If you put this function in a php page and watch this page in a browser, nothing will be displayed.

If you want the result to be displayed, you have to add `echo` before the function and this is exactly what the function that starts with `the_` are doing.

You may ask yourself why sometimes we want only the result to be **returned** by the function and **not** **displayed**. It's because sometime, we have to do some additional operations with the result before displaying it.

Example:

```
$content = get_the_content();

$content = str_replace('Hello', 'Bye', $content);

echo $content;
```

If not operation are needed so you only need to do:

```
the_content();
```

You also ask "How to implemenent it ?". To implement the function, you will have to add it in some specific `php files`. For example, for the `get_the_post_navigation()` function you will have to add it in the `single.php` file in your theme folder. You will need basics on php.